# Reading in Empty Cells with `read_excel` in Python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am using Python pandas to `read_excel`. This is the column I am reading in.

[image: Excel Snippet]

My problem is that read_excel isn't counting the empty cells as cells. When I use `df2=df1.iloc[0:30]`, I want it to include those empty cells so those last two data items are not included in my dataframe (this is because these cells are populated daily throughout the month, so those empty cells will exist until the very last day of the month). How do I ensure pandas read_excel includes those empty cells in its dataframe?

Comment: try adding parameter `skip_blank_lines=False` in your read function

Comment: This worked! Is there additional documentation other than https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html? I don't see that in the list of parameters.

Comment: It is undocumented as far as I know, but a hidden gem you get to know after dwelling on the internet for a while. :$

Comment: In pandas 1.1.4: `read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_blank_lines'`

Comment: @craq did you find an alternative ?

Comment: @diogeek I can't remember sorry. Did you try Lijo's answer below?

Comment: @craq I would, but I'm currently using the `read_excel_as_template` function of the `styleframe` module, which implicitely calls `pandas.read_excel`, so I can't use `fillna` as a workaround :(

Answer (score 5):

```
df = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx',header=None, skip_blank_lines=False)

       0
0     17
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      T
6   0.13
7   0.33
8   0.02
9   0.04
10     T
11     0
12     0
13  0.57
14     0
15     0
16     T
17     0
18     0
19  0.07
20     0
21     0
22  0.11
23     0
24     0
25   NaN
26   NaN
27   NaN
28   NaN
29   NaN
30   NaN
31  1.27
32     7
```

#Note: Count doesn't count NaN values.

```
df.count()
```

returns

```
0    27
dtype: int64
```

and

```
df.size
```

returns

```
33
```

Comment: what about `len(df)` @Scott

Comment: @pyd len(df) returns 33 it includes NaN as well as df.shape returns (33,1).

Comment: In pandas 1.1.4: `read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_blank_lines' `

Answer (score 2):

**skip_blank_lines** parameter is not valid in newer pandas version. Use code like be get the exact df as in the excel.

```
df = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx',dtype="str").fillna('')
```